# Is Hadoop the right tech for this?

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce

If I had millions of records of data, that are constantly being updated and added to every day, and I needed to comb through all of the data for records that match specific logic and then take that matching subset and insert it into a separate database would I use Hadoop and MapReduce for such a task or is there some other technology I am missing? The main reason I am looking for something other than a standard RDMS is because all of the base data is from multiple sources and not uniformly structured.

Answer (score 2):

Map-Reduce is designed for algorithms that can be parallelized and local results can be computed and aggregated. A typical example would be counting words in a document. You can split this up into multiple parts where you count some of the words on one node, some on another node, etc and then add up the totals (obviously this is a trivial example, but illustrates the type of problem).

Hadoop is designed for processing large data files (such as log files). The default block size is 64MB, so having millions of small records wouldn't really be a good fit for Hadoop.

To deal with the issue of having non-uniformly structured data, you might consider a NoSQL database, which is designed to handle data where a lot of a columns are null (such as MongoDB).

Comment: I think the query was more about batch vs real time processing in Hadoop.

Comment: In that case, no hadoop is not designed for real time processing.

Answer (score 1):

Hadoop/MR  are designed for batch processing and not for real time processing. So, some other alternative like [Twitter](http://engineering.twitter.com/2011/08/storm-is-coming-more-details-and-plans.html) [Storm](http://rebelic.nl/engineering/storm-is-hadoop-of-realtime-processing/), [HStreaming](http://www.hstreaming.com/) has to be considered.

Also, look at [Hama](http://incubator.apache.org/hama/) for [real time processing](http://codingwiththomas.blogspot.in/2011/10/apache-hama-realtime-processing.html) of data. Note that real time processing in Hama is still crude and a lot of improvement/work has to be done.

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend Storm or Flume. In either of these you may analyze each record as it comes in and decide what to do with it.

Answer (score 0):

If your data volumes are not great , and millions of records are not sounds as such I would suggest to try to get most from RDMBS, even if your schema will not be properly normalized.
I think even tavle of structure K1, K2, K3, Blob will be more useful t 
In NoSQL KeyValue stores are built to support schemaless data in various flavors but their query capability are limited. 
Only case I can think as usefull is MongoDB/ CoachDB capability to index schemaless data. You will be able to get records by some attribute value. 
Regarding Hadoop MapReduce - i think it is not useful unless you want to harness a lot of CPUs for your processing or have a lot of data or need distributed sort capability.